# how to send variable from js to phtml magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, addtocart

i want to pass the value of qty from js to my phtml file so how to proceed 
here is my code:

```
$("#qty").change(function () {
                            var value = Number($("#qty").val());
                            console.log(value);
                            if (value > 0) {
                                var variableToSend = document.getElementById('qty').value;
                                console.log(variableToSend);

                                $.post('Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml', {variable: variableToSend});

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: use hidden field

Comment: and what will be the value of this hidden input

Comment: <input class="qty-default" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ????; ?>">

Comment: qty is the id of box of the qty product that client put it

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot pass any data from JS to phtml directly. PHTML is executed at server side while JS is executed at client side. If you wanna pass any data to server you need to use either Ajax or Server request via GET/POST method.
Inorder to pass data from controller to phtml you could do this in your `execute()`

> ```
> $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
>
> /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
> $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
> $resultPage->getLayout()->initMessages();
> $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Clounce_hello')->setName($name);
> return $resultPage;
> ```

And in phtml, you could fetch it like this

> `<?php echo $this->getName(); ?>`

for more information please refer : 
https://www.clounce.com/magento/a-very-basic-magento-2-module-with-parameterized-template

Comment: ok so you mean i should pass this data to controller then send it to my phtml ??? ok but how to recuperate this variable from controller to phtml ???

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please refer it. Do let me know for any queries.

Comment: thanks for your replay